# Does Android Jelly Bean 4.1 Support Microphone Audio Input from mini USB Headset?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb, skype, microphone, headset

Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (WiFi) 16Gb device running Android Jelly Bean 4.1

This tablet has a 3.5mm jack for stereo audio out. No microphone jack. At least this is the way I'm reading the specs:  http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/tablets/tablets/SM-T2100ZWABTU

I want to run Skype on this tablet https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider

I have used Skype in my Win7 laptop with a USB headset for years with great results - high quality phone calls; as good as my home land-line phone and far better than magic jack.

Has anyone used this tablet in this configuration before or something close? Successfully?

Comment: I'd actually be surprised if the headphone jack wasn't a combined headphone/microphone jack. Have you tried any headset/microphone devices like [this one from Samsung](http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-EHS64-Premium-Stereo-Headset/dp/B007E839OA)? (EDIT: Updated the link - Amazon is a lot cheaper)

Comment: I wonder, why would you need a usb headset for your device? as dotVezz suggested, you should get a headset(with built in microphone) with your device, and that is way better then you think.At least that will do your skype-type-work efficiently without any trouble. And yes those can really give you standard sound quality as well.